# Efficient way to return a List<Item> from a List<Guid> efficiently?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to return a `List<Item>` by feeding a `List<Guid>` to a repository method as such

```
public async Task<List<Item>> GetListOfItems(List<Guid> guids)
{
}
```

I thought about making a `GetById` call in a `foreach` loop but I figured this many calls to the DB will just be inefficient.

I also thought about maybe using `context.Items.Where(x => x...Contains(guids))` but I don't know how to write it right.

The thing is I'm trying to do this efficiently, hopefully using EF Core but if not possible then using a stored procedure in SQL would do the job.

I'm not advanced enough to figure out the SQL so if it's possible in EF Core that would be awesome.

Comment: `context.Items.Where(x => guids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList()`? Obviously, you'll need to replace `Id` with the actual `Guid` property.

Comment: How big is `guids`?

Comment: @tymtam it could be as much as 50 max, but per user, so depending on the amount of user running this method it could be a high number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all items in one database roundtrip like this:

```cs
public async Task<List<Item>> GetListOfItems(List<Guid> guids)
{
  return await context.Items.Where(x => guids.Contains(x.Id)).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I see, however should it be `x => guids.Contains(x.Id)` or `x => x.Contains(x.guid)` ?

Comment: Should be this one: ``x => guids.Contains(x.Id)``

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Could you maybe explain why it is this way ? I'm confused with the syntax because it seems like this is querying the `Id`s against the `guids` list, which maybe it should be but I thought it should query the guids against the Items list.

Comment: Think about this: you want to search ``x.Id`` in ``guids`` list, so you try to find the database records that is in ``guids`` list or ``guids`` should contains the current ``x.Id``.

Comment: I see, thank you. And is it efficient for a very large amount of requests ? I'm limiting the list of guids to 50 elements, but if 1000 users request that method, would the SQL be efficient ?

Comment: It depends on how your table created and indexes. But this is a good way for searching in list and will convert to ``IN`` statement in the sql side